# PHP SOAP issue feeding in results

Tags: php, soap, simplexml

I'm trying to create a page that displays current results from CA Lottery using PHP. I've used XML before, but am having issues with SOAP. I found [this page](http://services.calottery.com/CALotteryService.asmx?op=GetCurrentGameInfo), but its not a lot of help.

I've put together the code below, and was able to get it to return an object. But I can't get it to feed in the results I need. Any help would be amazing.

```
try { 
    $options = array( 
        'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 
        'exceptions'=>true, 
        'trace'=>1, 
        'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    ); 
    $client = new SoapClient('http://services.calottery.com/CALotteryService.asmx?WSDL', $options);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<p>Exception Error!</p>";
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

echo '<p>Connection: Success;</p>';

try {
    $response = $client->GetCurrentGameInfo();  

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

$x = simplexml_load_string("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>".$response->GetCurrentGameInfoResult->any);

var_dump($x);
```

Comment: It is hard to understand your question. What are you trying to do? What are your expected results? What are your actual results?

Comment: print_r($response=>) is not syntactically correct btw and should be throwing up a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 var_dump($response);
 $x = simplexml_load_string("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>".$response->GetCurrentGameInfoResult->any);
 var_dump($x);
```

at the end of your script.  Kind of odd, but calottery is returning a fragment of XML in the response that needs to be further processed ( the simplexml_load_string ).

Comment: Ok, I added that to the script. One thing I'm confused about, is how I can parse data from the file. For example, there is an array within it called "MMDraw", how could I get the results (Result1,Result2,Result3,Result4,Result5,ResultMega) from there?

Comment: That's a new problem/question - still to be nice read this http://debuggable.com/posts/parsing-xml-using-simplexml:480f4dfe-6a58-4a17-a133-455acbdd56cb

Comment: Hey David, I read through that link and it helped quite a bit. Thanks!